# How do I output a file to a view while also validating a form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am fairly new to MVC app creation, but I have basic understanding. I am creating a page where I can add to and delete from a text file, but the view also contains a table listing all items in the text file.

My understanding so far is that I know how to read a file, and output it to a list, which I can then specify in the model and loop in my view, and I know how to validate an editor. I however can't figure out how to do both at the same time.

Example:

[image: Webpage]

"Data" should contain the data from a text file.
Any explanation or examples of how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. I'm not sure if I need to specify a list in my model and then add to the list via my edit action, or create an index action and do it there, or what.

Model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    public class UploadFiles
    {
        public List<string> Paygroups;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a paygroup.")]
        public string PayGroup { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.UploadFiles
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Paygroup Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Update Paygroup</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "UpdateFiles", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PayGroup, new {@class = "control-label"})
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.PayGroup, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.PayGroup)}})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PayGroup, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default"/>
    </div>
}
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Paygroups</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    @foreach (var paygroup in Model.Paygroups)
    {
        <td>@Model.Paygroups</td>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class UpdateFilesController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Default
        public ActionResult Edit()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(string Paygroup)
        {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            { 
            var PG = new List<UploadFiles>
            {
                new UploadFiles
                {
                    PayGroup = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/textfiles"), "paygroup.text"))
                }
            };
         }
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For both the single playgroup and the whole list to be shown on the same page, you could change the model accordingly, storing both the whole list in a `List<string>` object and the newly added playgroup in a `string` object.

```
public PaygroupViewModel
{
    public List<string> Paygroups;
    public string Paygroup;
}
```

In the `form` part, that is where you “generate” a new paygroup, you need to reference the single `Paygroup` property, that will also be the argument passed in the `HttpPost` action method (instead of the whole model)

In the view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Paygroup ... )
```

In the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(string Paygroup)
{
    myPaygroupsList = new List<string>();

    // populate the list from file

    // add the new Paygroup to the list
    myPaygroupsList.Add(Paygroup);

    // now create the model:
    PaygroupViewModel model = new PaygroupViewModel() 
    {
        Paygroups = myPaygroupsList
    };
    Return view(model);
}
```

Then, in the view, you can easily loop in the model list

```
@foreach (string paygroup in Model.Paygroups)
{ // build your table }
```

Comment: I've updated the code in my main post. I had a few questions...
1. Where is model specified in the controller? I see you are still sending it to the view, but the name does not exist because it was replaced in the HttpPost ActionResult with string Paygroup. Should it be `string paygroup, string model`?
2. Is how I setup my list correct?
3. Am I not using ModelState.IsValid anymore? I saw you removed it from the controller. Don't I need that to validate the Editor field?
4. Is my loop in my view setup properly? I get an error for `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: 1. You have to create a new instance of the model within the Edit action method 2. I don’t think, as I don’t see you adding the new paygroup string to the file 3. I haven’t added for brevity 4. You haven’t created an instance of the model (see point 1.) so that was predictable

Comment: The new paygroup would be added to the file once they click the add button. Right now I'm trying to focus on setting up the list and displaying it in the view while making sure my editor still validates, so I haven't added that code yet. How would I go about creating the new instance of the model?

Comment: @Xiodrade I’ve edited my answer. BTW this is standard MVC pattern, you should review your knowledge of it.

Comment: You're right. It is standard. I just think it wasnt clicking for me because I've formatted it differently in the past by setting the model data in list in the controller and then sending the list to the view like `return view(listname)`. I'm currently still getting that object error even though the model instance was created, but I'll try to figure it out myself. Thanks for your help.